# VBA - runtime error '2147217908 (80040e0c)'

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am getting this error: "Run-time error '2147217908 (80040e0c)' command text was not set for the command object". I am pretty new to VBA, help would be really appreciated! Referring to other stackoverflow errors/questions.

When I hit 'Debug' it highlights: 
     oRs.Open sSQL, oCn
Is there something wrong here?

```
'fixing:run time error '-2147467259 automation error unspecified error

Sub Unprotect_WorkSheet_With_Password()
Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "YourPassword"
End Sub



    Sub Consolidate()

    Dim sSQL        As String       'SQL String
    Dim oCn         As Object       'Connection
    Dim oRs         As Object       'Recordset
    Dim vFile       As Variant      'File Name
    Dim sCustomer   As String       'Customer ID
    Dim sItem       As String       'Inventory Item ID

'   Get filenames
    vFile = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ml\testdirectory\*.csv")

'   Create SQL
    While vFile <> vbNullString
        If sSQL <> vbNullString Then sSQL = sSQL & vbCr & "Union " & vbCr
        sCustomer = Split(vFile, "-")(0)
        sItem = Split(Split(vFile, "-")(1), ".")(0)
        sSQL = sSQL & "Select '" & sCustomer & "' as Customer, '" & sItem & "' as Item, * from [" & vFile & "]"
        vFile = Dir
        DoEvents
    Wend
'   Create Connection Objects
    Set oCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    oCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT = CSVDelimited"";"
    oRs.Open sSQL, oCn
    Debug.Print sSQL

    If Sheet1.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then Sheet1.ListObjects(1).Delete
    Sheet1.ListObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSrcQuery, _
        Source:=oRs, _
        Destination:=Sheet1.Range("C6")).QueryTable.Refresh

    oRs.Close
oCn.Close

    Set oRs = Nothing
    Set oCn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: what is sSQL???

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: As the code clearly says, it's a string. `Dim sSQL        As String` can't  be any more explanatory.

Comment: It's value, when it errors, I mean

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is with the connection string - I don't think that `CSVDelimited` is a valid format specification.  See the [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/delimited-columns/) entry.

Answer (score -1):

Compact and repair the accdb. Make sure that the database is properly closed and the user logged out, that will deal with the automation error.